# MS-DOS command to delete all files except one

Tags: ms-dos

Is there an MS-DOS command that allows me to delete all files except one?

Consider as an example the following files:

```
a.001  
a.002  
a.003  
a.exe  
a.c
```

Is there a command to delete all files except `a.c`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the `for` and `if` commands to accomplish this:

```
for %i in (*) do if not "%~i" == a.c del "%~i"
```

This goes through the current directory, and compares each file name to a.c.  If it doesn't match, the file is deleted.

Comment: +1 never would of thought of using this for a simple delete... Loads of good answers here!

Comment: @Wil, when you start using `for` regularly you come up with all kinds of crazy scenarios for it.  :)

Comment: How can this be modified so it uses another directory besides the current directory?  I tried changing the * to a path that ended with *.*, but no joy.

Comment: @Mike, you want something like "for %i in (A:\Some\Path\\*) do if not %~nxi == a.c del %i" Note that the path ends in *, to get the files in that folder, and that the comparison is against %~nxi, the name with no path. For destructive for loops like this, it's a good idea to do "for ... do echo %i" to see what files will be affected before running the "for ... do if ... del %i" command.

Comment: Better use `del "%i"`

Comment: As far as I know, there is no `or` operator for `if` in batch. So how would you delete all files except *two* (or *three*, *four*, ...) ?

Comment: @Munchkin, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8438511/91756 for some ways to simulate an or statement.

Comment: If you need the `IF` statement to be case insensitive, change it to `IF /I`.

Comment: I had to enclose `a.c` in double quotes for the equality check to pass `for %i in (*) do if not "%~i" == "a.c" del "%~i"`

Answer (score 21):

You could set the file to read only before deleting everything

```
attrib +r a.c
del *.*
attrib -r a.c
```

Comment: And if you care not to see all of the _access denied_ errors just add a `> nul 2>&1` to the end of the del line

Answer (score 11):

No, there isn't. I'd make a directory, copy the important file into it, erase *.*, and move the file back. Then delete the temp file.

```
mkdir temp
move a.c temp
erase *.*
move temp\* .
rmdir temp
```

Comment: +1 crude and technically @Feiht thief says a better way of doing it (so also gave +1 there), but for speed, this is the way I would do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
FOR %f IN (*.*) DO IF NOT [%f]==[a.c] DEL /Q %f
```

Comment: what benefit are the [ ] ?

Comment: @barlop: `%f` could have spaces in the filename.

Comment: @paradroid no that won't help for that if [4 r]==[4 r] echo equal  I've seen similar done by some, like with . instead of []. I could guess at why, but i'd rather hear it from somebody that does it.

Comment: @barlop: I have no idea what you just typed there, but the square brackets work just like quote marks would.

Comment: @paradroid C:\>if [4 r]==[4 r] echo abc <ENTER> gives result "r]==[4 was unexpected at this time."   Whereas  C:\>if "4 r"=="4 r" echo abc  gives result abc.  So what makes you think they in any way work like quote marks would?  Even C:\>if [a b]==[a b] echo abc   <-- does not work gives similar error. b]==[a was unexpected at this time.   So what makes you think they work like quotes?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1303/discussion-between-barlop-and-paradroid)

Comment: @paradroid   C:\>if [%USERPROFILE%]==[%USERPROFILE%] echo abc <ENTER>
and was unexpected at this time.  <-- [] make no difference. Also  even without the brackets, %f works look C:\>for /f "tokens=*" %f in ("a b") do IF %f==%f echo same <ENTER>

Comment: @paradroid  so brackets never have any effect on spaces. and %f in an IF just works with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-4" %%a in ('dir /a:-d /b /s %app_path%^|find /v "%file%"') DO Del /q %%a %%b %%c %%d
```

Comment: I think this would probably be helpful, if it were explained what it does. It looks like it traverses a whole folder tree, which is what I want. `%app_path%` and `%file%` are the root of the tree to traverse, and the file to avoid deleting, respectively. What is the `^`, and why are we passing four tokens per file to the `Del` command?

Answer (score 0):

For speed, I use [**delen**](http://adoxa.110mb.com/delenxrd/):

```
delen /! a.c
```

[**TCC/LE**](http://jpsoft.com/tccle_cmd_replacement.html) also has a more powerful `del` command:

```
del /[!a.c] *
```

Comment: `del /[!a.c] *` yelds `Invalid switch - "[!a.c]".`

Comment: @karlphillip: It works fine, **"in TCC/LE"**.